# How to change stylesheet tag in an xml in .NET

Tags: .net, xml

Is there a way for me to change the stylesheet tag in an xml. Is there a way to do that....
ex if I receive

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="www.somecompany.com/stylesheet.xsl"?>
<MedicalRecord>
......
......
</MedicalRecord>
```

I want to make it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="mystylesheet.xsl"?>
<MedicalRecord>
......
......
</MedicalRecord>
```

Note the href tag value has changed.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424613/xml-changing-the-value-of-an-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At it's simplest based on a straight replace:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
XmlProcessingInstruction pi = 
    (XmlProcessingInstruction)
         doc.SelectSingleNode("/processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet')");

// Replace href with the one we want
Regex r = new Regex("href=[\"']?((?:.(?![\"']?\\s+(?:\\S+)=|[>\"']))+.)[\"']?", 
                              RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);       
pi.Data = r.Replace(pi.Data, "href=\"mystyle.xsl\"", 1, 0);
```