# Writing a XML file with specific XML structure in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

I have one XML file (which is already exist) where I have to perform write operation. XML Structure is like this:

```
<IN.EM>
<Ch1>
<CONFIG_PARAM>
  <Item name="Base" value="0"/>
  <Item name="UpperLimt" value="0"/>
  <Item name="LowerLimit" value="0"/>
  <Item name="Label" value="1"/>
</CONFIG_PARAM>
</Ch1>
<Ch2>
<CONFIG_PARAM>
  <Item name="Base" value="0"/>
  <Item name="Upperimt" value="0"/>
  <Item name="LowerLimit" value="0"/>
  <Item name="Label" value="1"/>
</CONFIG_PARAM>
</Ch2>
 <CONFIG_PARAM>
  <Item name="Line" value="50"/>
  <Item name="Mark" value="1"/>
  <Item name="Language" value="LANG_ENG"/>
  <Item name="PID" value="001"/>
  <Item name="Formt" value="US"/>   
</CONFIG_PARAM>
</IN.EM>
```

How can I perform write operation here? So that I can assign new value to each attribute. For each Attribute I have property.

E.g. After performing write operation data should display `<Item name="Base" value= "10"/>` and after that I have to save this value and when next time I will launch my application it will show latest value.

P.S: I have edit data specific to node like whatever data coming in node ch1 has different property and ch2 node has different property and last CONFIG_PARAM node has different property. User may be change value of ch1 and not other in that I have to save default value for others.

UPDATE:

```
foreach (ConfigParameterNode node in ch1)
        {
            switch (node.Name)
            {
                case "Label":
                    doc.Root.Elements("Ch1").First(m => m.Attribute("name").Value == "Label").SetElementValue("value", cfg[0].Label.ToString());
                    doc.Save(path);
                    break;
                case "LowerLimit":
                    doc.Root.Elements("Ch1").First(m => m.Attribute("name").Value == "LowerLimit").SetElementValue("value", cfg[0].LowerLimit.ToString());
                    doc.Save(path);
                    break;
                case "UpperLimt":
                    doc.Root.Elements("Ch1").First(m => m.Attribute("name").Value == "UpperLimt").SetElementValue("value", cfg[0].UpperLimt.ToString());
                    doc.Save(path);
                    break;
                case "Base":
                   doc.Root.Elements("Ch1").First(m => m.Attribute("name").Value == "Base").SetElementValue("value", cfg[0].Base.ToString());
                    doc.Save(path);
                    break;
            }
}
```

Getting exception of nullReference: "Object reference is not set to instance of object"

Comment: Does the file exist already and you want to change the attribute values or will you write the file from scratch? Creating from scratch is obviously easy. Modifying: You can read the file into an `XmlDocument`, then use XPath expressions to get the desired nodes, modify the attributes and then write the XML file back.

Comment: xml file is already exist only I have to modify value and save it regarding each attribute. Please provide some sample code for my xml file. That would be more helpful for me.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. Please review [How To Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then update this showing what you have tried. (I would suggest just starting with creating the whole document with LINQ to XML – as an easier API to work with – before trying to modify a document. There are lots of samples out there, for example [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2008/02/28/linq-to-xml-creating-complete-xml-document.aspx).)

Comment: @user2932395 :-D I know - StackOverflow is great for turning vague questions into working code. But please, as `Richard` wrote, keep in mind that generating good answers depends on asking good questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out the XDocument Class
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)

You can append to the file like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load('filePath');
                doc.Root.Add(
                    new XElement("An Element Name",
                        new XAttribute("An Attribute", "Some Value"),
                        new XElement("Nested Element", "Inner Text"))
                    );
                doc.Save(filePath);
```

Or you can search for an element and update like this:

```
doc.Root.Elements("The element").First(m => m.Attribute("An Attribute").Value == "Some value to match").SetElementValue("The element to change", "Value to set element to");
doc.Save(filePath);
```

Comment: I have tried your way as well as tried this solution also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424613/xml-changing-the-value-of-an-attribute but problem it's upting first value not all. Please tell me how can I update all the value. Because I have property through which I'm updating value in xml file.

Comment: Can you update your question to show what C# code you have regarding this problem? Thanks!

Comment: I have added my c# which I'm using to edit value in my existing xml file.

Comment: Try changing ".SetElementValue("...");" to ".SetAttributeValue("...")".
If that doesn't fix it then try and find where the Null Reference is and post that.