# Replace a string in an XML string

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have a string that looks like this:

```
newNodeXML = "<item id="qDf73w8emTg" parent_id="weLPzE243de" type="suite">
                 <content>
                    <name>Three</name>
                 </content>
              </item>"
```

**In my [WebMethod]**, I am trying to replace the parent_ID (randomly generated during run-time) like this:

```
Regex myRegex = new Regex(@""" parent_id=""(.*?)"" type=""");
newNodeXML = myRegex.Replace(newNodeXML, "d43df2qT45");
```

*Please NOTE that for example/demo sake I have used 'd43df2qT45' in the second line above. I will actually be generating that randomly too.*

**My problem** here is that the result of this comes out to be.
I **do not want** this:

```
<item id="qDf73w8emTgd43df2qT45suite">
   <content>
      <name>Three</name>
   </content>
</item>
```

Instead, this is what I **want** it to be:

```
<item id="qDf73w8emTg" parent_ID="d43df2qT45" type="suite">
   <content>
      <name>Three</name>
   </content>
</item>
```

P.S. I have tried some examples/google searches and all I could find were examples that got me this far.

Comment: Regex is probably the wrong way of doing this. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424613/xml-changing-the-value-of-an-attribute

Comment: Is the length of `parent_id` value fixed and known beforehead?

Comment: Why don't you deserialize this content, change what you need and then serialize it again?

Comment: Are you looking specifically for a regex solution?

Comment: I am fine with any solution to tackle this. Doesn't have to specifically regex. But I guess @Guffa's answer just worked. If anyone thinks regex is not the most efficient way to approach this problem, please feel free to suggest alternatives.

Comment: @supersophisticated Regex is ok, just be sure that it's not a bottleneck in your application and that you and your co-workers are able to decrypt the pattern. You can get beck to the project month later and don't know what it does just by looking at it ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use parentheses to catch the part before and after the value, then use `$1` and `$2` to include them in the replacement:

```
Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"( parent_id="")[^""]+("")");
newNodeXML = myRegex.Replace(newNodeXML, "$1" + "d43df2qT45" + "$2");
```

You can also do it using just string operations:

```
int pos1 = newNodeXML.IndexOf(" parent_id=\"") + 12;
int pos2 = newNodeXML.IndexOf('"', pos1);
newNodeXML = newNodeXML.Substring(0, pos1) + "d43df2qT45" + newNodeXML.Substring(pos2);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have a known XML structure, using XML tools is probably better idea than using refex, and faster too. For example:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(newNodeXML);
doc.Root.Attribute("parent_id").Value = "xyz";
```

This code relies on the exact structure you provided. So there's only one `item`, it's the root of an XML file and it has an attribute called `parent_id`.

More about the `XDocument` type on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Actually, using a regular expression is about twice as fast as parsing the string as XML.

Comment: @Guffa I haven't test it, you might be right for this particular scenario. But from my experience, XML performs much better than regex for larger documents. But speed is not the only reason I would not go with regex. Readability is another one. Also I'm always trying to suggest solutions that OP might not be aware of in order to learn him something new :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you've hardcoded everything, there is really no need to use capture group's.
Just extend the replacement to this:

```
"\" parent_id=\"" + "d43df2qT45" + "\" type=\""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this, I tested it and it seems to work:

```
String newXml = Regex.Replace(xml, "parent_id=\".+\" ", "parent_id=\"" + newID + "\" ");
```

Here is a sample method to test it:

```
String xml = "<item id=\"qDf73w8emTg\" parent_id=\"weLPzE243de\" type=\"suite\">\n\t<content>\n\t\t<name>Three</name>\n\t</content>\n</item>";
String newID = "This is the new parent_Id";
Console.WriteLine("Old xml: \n\n" + xml + "\n\n\nNew xml:\n");
String newXml = Regex.Replace(xml, "parent_id=\".+\" ", "parent_id=\"" + newID + "\" ");
Console.WriteLine(newXml);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Just paste it inside the main method of a console app, and include the RegularExpression library :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for what your wanting to do by using a regex like below.

```
Regex myRegex = new Regex("parent_id=\"([^""]+)\");
string myXml = "<myxml>data</myxml>";
xdoc.LoadXml(myXml);
```